# How to get the Config of a Bundle directly in the Container like the Parameters

Tags: symfony

I created a bundle in order to load my custom config file.
My config file looks like this and is called cronjob_properties.yaml:

```
cronjob_properties:
    task:
        name: 'all_items'
```

My extension loaded in a Bundle called PropertiesBundle looks like this

```
class CronjobPropertiesExtension extends Extension implements PrependExtensionInterface
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new CronjobPropertiesConfiguration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
    }
}
```

My config file is correctly parsed.
Then I have a config tree builder for validating the config file.

```
class CronjobPropertiesConfiguration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
{
    $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder('cronjob_properties');
    $treeBuilder->getRootNode()
        ->children()
            ->arrayNode('task')
                ->children()
                    ->scalarNode('name')->end()
                ->end()
            ->end() //task
        ->end();

    return $treeBuilder;
}
```

Now I want to use the configuration in my application.
What I tried so far is to read the config file directly from ContainerInterface

like this

```
$this->container['cronjob_properties']
```

but this doesn't work.
I found in the documentation that i need to manually parse the Yaml file and then call processConfiguration.
Is there an easier way to access my configuration file from a controller for example or any other class in the project ?

Comment: In your extension, you can set the parameters that you need when you process the configuration. It's not possible to read the config directly from other parts of the app.

Comment: It's a common mistake to think that the contents of the various config files are automatically accessible via the container.  As several other people have mentioned, it just does not work that way.  You might consider creating some sort of CronjobManager class and then initialize the service in your extension using your config properties.  That will get you away from using parameters directly in your app code.  It's basically what most bundles do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your Extension class, in the load method, set the parameter:

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new CronjobPropertiesConfiguration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $container->setParameter('foobar', $config['foobar']);
}
```

Comment: @claudio-ferraro please mark this as the answer if it answers your question. If not, please let me know and I will try to help.